# Which etiquette are being used, and in what order?

Tags: shadowrun-returns, shadowrun-dragonfall

In *Shadowrun: Dragonfall*, I am playing a Samurai with high Charisma, and am trying to use much etiquette as possible. The issue is, etiquette are pretty narrow in application and in my playthrough I keep getting them in the wrong order.

What I am looking for is a spoiler-free list of etiquette to pick up each time I gain a choice, and the order I should pick. (For instance, there's a side-quest, early in the game where you will need both Corporate and/or Security etiquette.)

Answer (score 3):

1. **Security** is the most useful one.
2. **Corporate** would be the second most useful.
3. **Gang** is the last one.

Having a charisma 6 will be extremely helpful too to avoid some fights.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [in-depth etiquette analyst and breakdown](https://www.reddit.com/r/shadowrunreturns/comments/ceguah/dragonfall_etiquette_analysis/) by `u/noqnnoqn` in reddit, `security` is more or less an ok-isshh choice if you have a lot of charisma since:

> **Security** seems useful with its seven checks, but a closer look paints
> another picture: 5/7 checks can be alternatively solved with Easy
> Charisma checks. One of the remaining two checks requires a subsequent
> a Hard Charisma check, leaving only one useful check for 4-5 Charisma
> builds. **Valid choice for a 2-3 Charisma build, otherwise debatable**.
>
> Via - u/noqnnoqn

And this is what he concluded his analysis with:

```
1. Socialite.....¥¥¥!!!
2. Street........Highest general usefulness.
3. Academic......Situationally useful for a few important conversations. 
4. Security......Excellent pick for low Charisma builds.
5. Gang..........At least it's not Corporate.
6. Corporate.....Worse than Gang.
7. Shadowrunner..Worse than Socialite.
```

He however added that this list varies from build to build since Deckers & Riggers for example have little use for Academic as Intelligence checks serve as alternatives for two of the three Academic checks.